# Using VBA, Not able to store the cell value in a variable and throws 1004 error

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I am in learning phase in vba. I am trying to store a value in a variable but not able do with Cell and also Range and it throws an 1004 error

Below is my code

```
Sub myself()

Dim str As String
Dim rock As String
Dim MaxStrLen As Integer
Dim StrLen As String
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastCol As Long
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer

Dim FilePath As String

Set ws1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = Sheets("Sheet2")

LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
LastCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Open "C:\Users\Antony\Desktop\test.txt" For Output As #2

ws1.Activate

With ws1
For i = 0 To LastRow
For j = 0 To LastCol
```

**.Range(.Cells(i, j)).Value = str**

```
Next j

Next i

Print #2, str
End With

Close #2

End Sub
```

Highlighted line is the 1004 error. Please help to solve and store in a variable in Notepad.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Range expects two cells, a start and a finish.  Just use `.Cells(i, j).Value = str`

Comment: I think he wants the value of the cell stored in the variable `str`, so need to flip the sides of that assignment: `str = .Cells(i, j).Value`

Comment: And to output each cell value individually in your loop, move the `Print` line within your inner `For j` loop, or else you'll only ever print out the last value.

Comment: str = .Cells(i, j).Value     tried this line too still throws an error 1004

Comment: @AntonyPPeter The problem is that your For loops start at 0.  There is no row 0 and there is no column 0, that's what's causing your error.  Change your loops to start at 1.

Comment: @tigeravatar you are right, I corrected now and its working fine thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just use

```
.Cells(i, j).Value = str
```

BTW you'd better explicitly qualify your range references up to the `worksheet` object (and, if multiple workbooks are involved, up to the `workbook` object) , otherwise it would implicitly assumed `ActiveSheet` (and ActiveWorkbook)

so, instead of

```
LastRow= Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
LastCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
```

use

```
LastRow= ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
LastCol = ws1.Cells(1, ws1.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
```

or

```
With ws1
    LastRow= .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    LastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
End With
```

---

so your code could be refactored as follows:

```
Option Explicit

Sub myself()

    Dim str As String
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim LastCol As Long
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long

    Dim FilePath As String

    Set ws1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set ws2 = Sheets("Sheet2")


    Open "C:\Users\Antony\Desktop\test.txt" For Output As #2

    With ws1
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        LastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column

        For i = 1 To LastRow
            For j = 1 To LastCol
                str = .Range(.Cells(i, j)).Value
                Print #2, str
            Next
        Next
    End With

    Close #2

End Sub
```

Comment: Initially I tried the same but it shows the same error.

Comment: @DisplayName the problem isn't how he's defining the end, it's how he's defining the beginning.  From his original post: `For i = 0 To LastRow` Because there is no row 0, it will always result in the 1004 error.

Comment: but it's the right syntax, so what's the outcome now?

Comment: You are correct, syntax is fine.  OP just need to make his For loop start at an actual row number instead of 0

Comment: I used both options still it fails to execute

Comment: @tigeravatar, you're right. that is the root of the 1004. and then she has to use the right syntax, too

Comment: Cells start at (1,1).

Comment: I tried the options you shared but still it fails by mentioning the same error

Comment: I got it now... For i = 1 To LastRow
    For j = 1 To LastCol

Comment: I initialised by 0...thats y the error...thank you so much for your time

Comment: see edited answer for a complete code where I also adopted: 1) the switching of `str` and `.Range(.Cells(i, j)).Value` (as noticed by @tigeravatar) 2) enclosed the `Print #2, str` inside the nested  loop

Comment: @DisplayName I used your code and its working fine. thanks

Comment: @AntonyPPeter, you are welcome. You may then consider marking the answer as accepted. Thank you